# Tool to track application installer actions? (Win)

Tags: windows, operating-system, windows-installer, installation

I need to find out all the file system and registry operations that installer of some application performs. Is there a software tool for this?

OS is Windows XP, if that matters.

Answer (score 3):

Look into the [Windows SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default.aspx) Utilities.

Specifically [RegMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896652.aspx) & [FileMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642.aspx)

Comment: what about registering dlls. it's not done through registry, is it?

Comment: Yes.  Registering DLLs is by definition done through the registry.

Comment: RegMon and FileMon have been superseded by Process Monitor (ProcMon)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about tracking file system changes, but you can export the Windows registry as text before and after the install, and then use a diff tool to see what's changed.  [There's an O'Reilly hack about that here.](http://oreilly.com/pub/h/2887)

You could conceivably do the same with a DIR/S at the root of your drive, although it would be pretty time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use one of those "uninstall monitoring programs" ?

[Total Uninstall](http://www.martau.com/) is the first that comes to mind, although there is a bunch of them, really.

Answer (score 0):

[This site](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msi/tips.htm) has a list of some installer monitors.